# Hiding Field(s) if Date is Expired

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm using Drupal 7 date field. Using views, when the date has expired, the page goes to a section labeled 'past events.' In the template page, the date and time are both separated for instance. $date_output and $time_output. I need to hide the time field after the date has expired. any ideas?

Comment: You probably need to explain this a little more. Is there any specific reason why you can't compare with the current date and hide the date/time fields?

Comment: thats what I'm looking for apparently. How to do the compare. I've followed a few tuts but not seem to work.

Comment: Can you show us the template page you are referring in the question?

Answer (score 0):

If your date is in one of the [supported date/time formats](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php), you can use strtotime() and date() to compare.  Wrap the printing of $time_output in an if statement.  For example:

```
if ( strtotime($date_output) > date() ) {
  // $date_output is greater than now, eg, not expired
  print($time_output);
}
```

If $date_output is already a timestamp, no need to use strtotime()

Comment: Ok so this is what I'm working with. The 'time' div should be hidden if the date has past. This is what I have.  Trying to see if this works also. I want to show my div based on a date expiration. Here is what I have 

    <?php if (isset($_POST['org']) && $_POST['org'] == "yes") {
      echo "<div class="time event-info">
            <span class="heading">Time</span>
            <span class="info"><?php print render($time_output); ?></span>";
    } else {
      echo "<div id='layer' style='display: none'>";
    }  ?>

Comment: include in your existing if statement, so it shows as:
if (isset($_POST['org']) && $_POST['org'] == "yes" && strtotime($date_output) > date()) {

Comment: Or do you mean to say that $date_output is not available in the script rendering $time_output? In that case, is this your time field template? The template should have access to the node or entity containing the date field, you may have to check that to get the date output value.

Comment: its all relative to the date. if the date has past, then the time shouldnt show.

Comment: hence using the date in your if statement.  does the script you posted, that prints $time_output, have access to $date_output?

Comment: ok. figured it out. thought i'd share.    <?php if (isset($time_output) && $time_output != '' && $date_timestamp > date('U') ):?>
    <div class="time event-info">
        <span class="heading">Time</span>
        <span class="info"><?php print render($time_output); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>